# Hiding isotope elements on page load

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I'm having problems with hiding isotope elements on page load. I followed the explanation given at https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/56. However although the element I want to hide is not being shown (using "opacity:0" in the css), it is leaving a blank space.

You can see it at http://whatcanido.co.uk/pace/. It is the first item in the grid.

If you then hover over the "by expertise" item in the top menu, and click on "Architecture" it comes up fine.

I am using someone else's Wordpress theme which I am adapting and can't figure out why the blank space is being left.

I need the first item hidden, until the filter is activated.

I would appreciate any help.

Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't you give all the initial items a class to filter.

Try to give all items that should be visible on the first page a class `.init` and filter for that:

```
$('#container').isotope({ filter: '.init' });
```

I never used isotope but i think it should work after reading a few rows in the docs.